# PHP in echo'd HTML

Tags: php, html, if-statement, header, echo

If you're not logged in and don't have the id, the header should include "Inloggen" en "Aanmelden", if one is logged in and has the id, it should show "Uitloggen" which means "Logout". I'm echoing the HTML code, but I also want to run a PHP if else statement in the HTML code.

Header.php:

```
<?php

echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="../Campingmaasvallei/images/logocamping2.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Campingmaasvallei/css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Campingmaasvallei/css/style.css">
    <title>Camping Maasvallei</title>
</head>

<body class="body-login">
    <header>        
        </div>
        <div class="container-header">
             <a href="index.php?home.php"> <img id="logo" src="../Campingmaasvallei/images/logocamping2.png"> </a> 
            <nav>
                <li><a href="index.php?home.php">Home</a></li>  
                <li><a href="index.php?page=omgeving">Omgeving</a></li>  
                <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
                    <li><a href="index.php?page=login">Inloggen</a> </li>    
                    <li><a href="index.php?page=aanmelden">Aanmelden</a> </li>                
                }
                else{
                    <li><a href="index.php?page=logout">Uitloggen</a> </li>
                ?>
            </nav>
        </div>  
    </header>
    <div class="container">';
?>
```

Comment: Don't `echo` the HTML. Just close `?>` PHP, put the HTML code there, and have regular `<?php ?>` blocks inside your HTML…

Comment: See how to properly write the [alternative syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (your PHP tags aren't closed/opened in the right places).

Comment: You choose probably the worst way for combining PHP and HTML, consider using some template engine like Smarty, or even some MVC framework like Laravel or maybe just... varaibales. BTW except of wrong code pattern you have also obvious errors in the HTML itself, like closing `</div>` which wasn't opened at all (second line inside your `<body>`)

Comment: @biesior PHP itself is already a decent templating language. While there are reasons to use Smarty and the like, that'd be overkill here.

Comment: @deceze In single script it would be overkill, therefore I added *maybe just... varaibales*. For larger projects, using spaghetti code is considered as a suicidal tendency. Of course without knowledge what finally OP wants to get, we can just think about hypothetical considerations

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code in your file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" href="../Campingmaasvallei/images/logocamping2.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Campingmaasvallei/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Campingmaasvallei/css/style.css">
  <title>Camping Maasvallei</title>
</head>

<body class="body-login">
  <header>
    </div>
    <div class="container-header">
      <a href="index.php?home.php"> <img id="logo" src="../Campingmaasvallei/images/logocamping2.png"> </a>
      <nav>
        <li><a href="index.php?home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=omgeving">Omgeving</a></li>
        <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])): ?>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=login">Inloggen</a> </li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=aanmelden">Aanmelden</a> </li>
        <?php else:?>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=logout">Uitloggen</a> </li>
        <?php endif;?>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])){ ?>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=login">Inloggen</a> </li>    
                <li><a href="index.php?page=aanmelden">Aanmelden</a> </li>                
           <?php }else{ ?>
                <li><a href="index.php?page=logout">Uitloggen</a> </li>
           <?php } ?>
```